# Laravel queue stops randomly without exception

Tags: database, laravel, redis, queue

I have a laravel queue setup with a

```
database
```

Connection. Note this problem is also on redis. But i am currently using the database connection for the

```
failed_jobs
```

Table to help me check any errors that occur during the queue process.

The problem i have is that the queue stops working after a few jobs without any message showing why. But when i restart the command (php artisan queue:work) it picks up the remaining jobs. And continues. (But stops again later)

The job is configured with these values

```
public $tries = 1;
public $timeout = 10;
```

The job code is, (Not original code)

```
    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            $file = //function to create file;
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $zip->open(//zip_path);
            $zip->addFile(//file_path, //file_name);
            $zip->close();
            @unlink(//remove file);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e);
        }
    }
```

And the failed function is setup like this:

```
public function failed(\Exception $exception)
{
    Log::error($exception);
    $this->fail($exception);
    $this->delete();
}
```

But my there is no failed_job row, And my log is empty

Edit: I added simple info logs after every line of code. And every time i start the queue, It stops after the last line. So the code runs correct. So laravel doesn't start the new job after that

Comment: what happens if you replace this handle with a simpler version such as "echo, log only" to see whether it is related to the code or something else. Don't forget to restart the queue

Comment: @Ersoy I did that. And that keep the queue alive with all the echo's showing in the terminal. So it is something with my code. But it is weird that it reaches the end of the code the job has to process. And then stop. So unlink is the last line. I added an extra log after the unlink. And that logges correct

Comment: Do you think any script or command may be executing `php artisan queue:restart` (cron, minutely command etc maybe) - this command ends every running process after the completion.

Comment: Nope. I checked the code again. And there are np signs of a restart command or something that could kill the queue

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by increasing memory limit public like this in my code

```
$tries = 10;

    public $timeout = 4000;
    protected $news;

    public function __construct($news)
    {
        ini_set('memory_limit', '4048M');
        $this->news = $news;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried `queue:listen` ?

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

Also i guess you need the [Supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker) to keep your worker alive.

Comment: Yes. I tried using listen. And that works. The queue keeps working. But after doing more research about the command, It isn't the best to run in production due to the more resources it uses.

Answer (score 1):

so what you need here to solve the issue is to do the following steps :

1. go to **bootstrap/cache/** remove all file .PHP
2. go to the src and run php artisan queue:restart
3. Now after adding the snippet, we need to trigger the following commands respectively:

- sudo supervisorctl reread  *(to check the file content and make sure
  that the snippet is correctly set)*
- sudo supervisorctl update  *(release the config changes under the supervisor)*
- sudo supervisorctl restart all  *(re-trigger the queues so that the newly created queue gets initialized and start picking up messages respectively)*